Asked to suggest referees 9 months after submission: what to do?
I submitted a research paper to a mainstream journal of my math subject domain in December 2023. I did not hear anything from them since, so last month I reached out to them. My editor informed me that she had sent my paper in January 2024 to two referees, none of whom have responded to her invitation till now. She then asked me to suggest "a few names" of some people who I believe could be "good referees" for my paper. She said that she would choose two of them anonymously and invite them to referee my paper but if they too eventually don't respond, then my paper will be rejected.
There are various situations I am thinking about. Most of these have been described in THIS post (suggested to me in the comment below).
The simplest thing is to go ahead and suggest her some names from my field. In this regard, my question (which has not been answered in the above post) is this: can I suggest the names of two people who are acknowledged in my paper? Will it be ethical? I am leaning towards suggesting them because those are the only two people I can GUARANTEE will agree to referee my paper.
Another thing I can do is withdraw my paper from the journal without suggesting her referees or waiting anymore. While the journal is not very prestigious, I am sure I will submit some of my other papers to this journal in the future (2-3 years). I am an early career researcher and I have seen a decent number of papers from my math field getting published here in the last 10-15 years. My question (which has not been answered in the above post) is this: By withdrawing my paper now in response to the editor's above message, can I come across as rude or arrogant and potentially sabotage my chances of publishing in this journal in the future?

This question is similar to: The editor cannot find a referee to my paper after one year. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Anyon Thanks, I edited my question to be more precise, and I have now indicated why the question you mentioned above does not address my concerns here.

The question in the body "Can I suggest people I acknowledged" is unrelated to the title question. Please ask one question per post.

What makes you certain that the suggested reviewers will agree to review?

@Allure I have to suggest a few names and the editor will choose two of them. Of course, I am not certain the two people she randomly chooses will agree to review. I suppose that is a risk I have to take. This situation is also discussed here https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/164007/the-editor-cannot-find-a-referee-to-my-paper-after-one-year.

@Katrina You've written the only two people I can GUARANTEE will agree to referee my paper. How can you be sure these two people will review your paper?

Oh, those two people had some relationship with me while I was carrying out my research, they were interested in my paper and they are editors and reviewers for other journals. In fact, I also kept them in the loop in my 9-month review process. While I did not confirm this with them explicitly recently, given their relationship with me, I am assuming they will agree to referee this paper. Maybe "guarantee" was a strong word.

@Katrina It could be that they decline citing a conflict-of-interest, then.

@Allure thanks, that's a good point I did not think about.

"she had sent my paper in January 2024 to two referees, none of whom have responded to her invitation till now" -- well, that's poor stewardship of the journal on the editor's behalf: These two are not likely ever going to respond now, eight months later. The editor should have looked for others in February already...

@WolfgangBangerth That's why I was also thinking about moving to another journal, but slightly concerned about starting the whole process afresh and if it's the right step. But I think if I suggest new referees now, it will still be "pretty much" the fresh start of the process.

@katrina: Well, have that conversation with the editor. You don't lose much if you go back and forth with the editor for a few days, explaining your questions and asking for their advice. Perhaps they say that they have one review but need a second one (in which case it'd be a shame to just withdraw). Or perhaps they're completely oblivious to the situation and then you know for sure. In any case, having a conversation never hurts.

Yes, you can suggest people you acknowledge in the paper. It should be obvious to the editor that there is some relationship and that the likelihood is of a positive review. You should, however, point out that they are acknowledged. The editor is the one making decisions about whether to invite them and how to evaluate their review, so there is no ethical issue. It might be wise to suggest a couple of others, however.
Withdrawing and submitting elsewhere is also an option, but probably not a better one. For some papers (maybe in math especially) there are a limited number of qualified reviewers in the world and another journal's reviewer stable might overlap with this one. But, I wouldn't consider it rude.

You’re overthinking the issue. She asked you to suggest names, so suggest names. That’s all there is to it. Any ethical implications of who the journal chooses to ask to review your paper are the responsibility of the journal and not your concern. This is assuming you are not hiding any material information on your relationship with the prospective referees you are suggesting (e.g., that one of them is a family member), and that you have not corruptly colluded with or bribed any of the people you are suggesting to guarantee a positive outcome.
Do not suggest your PhD advisor or any other person who has an obvious conflict of interest. Even if you are not hiding the nature of the relationship, such a person cannot be used as a referee. However, just being named in the acknowledgements does not constitute a conflict. And it’s expected that you suggest people who are somewhat familiar with the paper, so it’s quite likely such a person might be mentioned in the acknowledgements.
You can withdraw the paper, and I don’t see a reason why that should hurt you, but I don’t see how it would help either. You may as well try out the editor’s suggestion first and see what happens.

"However, just being named in the acknowledgements does not constitute a conflict. And it’s expected that you suggest people who are somewhat familiar with the paper" Really? Maybe this is a difference in math, but I am picturing an acknowledgement like "Thanks to Dr. Romik for his helpful feedback on an earlier draft" wouldn't be an appropriate reviewer. Maybe "Thanks to Dr. X for sharing her data on OSF" wouldn't constitute a conflict

@AzorAhai editors look for the most objective reviewer out of the pool of qualified people. So if I am thanked for providing feedback on a paper, it probably makes it less likely that an editor would ask me to review the paper. But (in pure math at least) no one will think it’s especially ethically problematic for me to be a reviewer for that reason. And to the limited extent that it may be perceived as problematic, I’d argue that asking the author of a paper to recommend reviewers (whether they are people who were mentioned in the acknowledgements or not) is far more problrmatic.

I suppose, for me, anyone I am thanking in the acknowledgements is too close of a collaborator to be a reviewer, since why else would they have read my manuscript? Haha. I suppose. I also dislike the practice, but I am now in the habit of generating potential reviewers as I write a paper from people I'm citing that don't know me/my PIs.

@AzorAhai it’s certainly possible that someone named in the acknowledgements would be too close to the author to serve as referee. Those two things are correlated, but one is not the cause of the other. And if there was a rule that people named in the acknowledgements could not serve as reviewers, many papers could not be reviewed effectively…

It seems we have very different norms about acknowledgements, then.

There're two different questions in the OP:

can I suggest the names of two people who are acknowledged in my paper? Will it be ethical?

The danger here is that the reviewers will have a conflict of interest. If they are acknowledged, then they presumably have firsthand knowledge of the work. For many editors/publishers that would be sufficient to disqualify them as reviewers; for other editors/publishers it could still be OK as long as the conflict of interest is disclosed.
You can pass the decision to the editor by disclosing that the suggested reviewers are acknowledged. If the editor invites them anyway, then it would be on the editor. Because there's a chance the editor will say no, you might want to suggest other, non-acknowledged reviewers as well to speed things up slightly.

By withdrawing my paper now in response to the editor's above message, can I come across as rude or arrogant and potentially sabotage my chances of publishing in this journal in the future?

Probably not. Journals see so many papers that most individual papers fade into the background. If your paper is unique in some way - which doesn't have to be the academic content, it could e.g. be if you submitted as a solo author while a PhD student and listed three different affiliations - then the editor might remember it. Even then they're unlikely to take retributive action. It's ultimately the author's prerogative which journal to submit to; furthermore if they agree that 9 months with no visible sign of review reflects badly on them (most people would), then they're more likely to be embarrassed than angry.

I don't think it follows from the quoted part that the reviewers will have a conflict of interest, though OP's comments certainly make it seem that way. Similarly, in general, I don't believe "We thank X for helpful discussions" implies a firsthand knowledge of the work, but the comment stating "while I was carrying out my research, they were interested in my paper" make that interpretation likely.
